# How do I take a string as input using getopt in python

Tags: python

I wanted to take the filepath as the input in the following reverse image search script , how do I do that?

````
import requests
filePath = "C:\\path\\test.jpg"
searchUrl = 'https://yandex.ru/images/search'
files = {'upfile': ('blob', open(filePath, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
params = {'rpt': 'imageview', 'format': 'json', 'request': '{"blocks":[{"block":"b-page_type_search-by-image__link"}]}'}
response = requests.post(searchUrl, params=params, files=files)
query_string = json.loads(response.content)['blocks'][0]['params']['url']
img_search_url= searchUrl + '?' + query_string
print(img_search_url)```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your arguments are in `sys.argv`.

```
import sys
import requests
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("You must specify a file name.")
    sys.exit(-1)
filePath = sys.argv[1]
...
```